# MQTT TLS not working in Raspberry Pi3

Tags: pi-3, mqtt

Has anybody got MQTT with TLS working in Pi3 ? If so, please help me to fix my problem.I am using MQTT 1.4 version.

I did following steps-

1. I generated both client and server cert files as per https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-tls-7.html.
2. I am trying to run MQTT with TLS but getting error: tlsv1: alert unknown ca.

I have following every steps properly for generating cert files for both client and server but do not understand why mqtt broker is not accepting client cert.

Thanks,

Jyoti Raj Sharma